# AngularJS small test, help me find the error please

Tags: javascript, angularjs

http://codepen.io/rcidaleassumpo/pen/ogvoQy

Hello, the code is on the site above.

Thats the HTML

```
  <div ng-app="testApp" ng-controller="myController">
  <select name="current" id="current" ng-model="currentliga">
      <option ng-repeat="liga in ligas">{{ liga }}</option>
  </select>

  {{ valor | currency:"R$" }}
  </div>
```

Thats the JS:

```
  var app = angular.module('testApp', []);

  app.controller('myController', function($scope){
     $scope.ligas = ['Bronze', 'Prata', 'Ouro', 'Platina', 'Diamante'];
     var preco = $scope.currentliga;
      switch(preco){
        case 'Bronze':
          $scope.valor = 24;
          break;
      }
   });
```

So basically my idea is to get the value from $scope.currentLiga, which is linked with the what the person will set as an option, and then return a value for the "preco" that will change the "valor" 
So, if its 'Bronze" that the people selects, the $scope.valor should change to 24.
What am I missing? 
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$watch`:

```js
var app = angular.module('testApp', []);

app.controller('myController', function($scope) {
  $scope.ligas = ['Bronze', 'Prata', 'Ouro', 'Platina', 'Diamante'];

  $scope.$watch('currentliga', function(newValue, oldValue) {
    switch (newValue) {
      case 'Bronze':
        $scope.valor = 24;
        break;
    }
  });


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="testApp" ng-controller="myController">
  <select name="current" id="current" ng-model="currentliga">
    <option ng-repeat="liga in ligas">{{ liga }}</option>
  </select>

  {{ valor | currency:"R$" }}
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you my friend, Can you please give an explanation on why I cant use my old option and why are you using this option? Because what you did was awesome, I appreciate , but I would like just the reason why this is working. if you could of course ;) Thank you anyways.